# How do I flip numerical data in R?

Tags: r

I am an R beginner but have thus far been able to find answers to my questions by googling. After a few days of searching I still can't figure this out though.

I have a dataset with cognitive test results. Most tests are scored so that higher scores are better. ONE test is scored in the opposite way, so that lower scores are better (completion time of the task). I want to combine three tests (so values from three columns in my dataframe) but first I need to flip the values of this one test.

By flip I mean that my lowest value (i.e. fastest completion time and best score) instead gets the highest value and that the highetst value (i.e. the slowest completion time and worst score) gets the lowest value. My data is numerical.

I have tried the dense_rank() function as well as the rev() function. dense_rank() returns a vector where the values are ranked but where the spread of the values are not kept and rev() only reverses the order of the values in the vector, it does not change the values themselves.

Example code:

```
> (.packages())
 [1] "readxl"       "rethinking"   "parallel"     "rstan"        "StanHeaders"  "uwIntroStats"
 [7] "ggplot2"      "dplyr"        "quantreg"     "SparseM"      "foreign"      "aod"         
[13] "stats"        "graphics"     "grDevices"    "utils"        "datasets"     "methods"     
[19] "base"

> testresults <- seq(from = 12, to = 120, by = 2)
> 
> testresults
 [1]  12  14  16  18  20  22  24  26  28  30  32  34  36  38  40  42  44  46  48  50  52  54  56  58
[25]  60  62  64  66  68  70  72  74  76  78  80  82  84  86  88  90  92  94  96  98 100 102 104 106
[49] 108 110 112 114 116 118 120
> test.frame <- data.frame(testresults, rev(testresults), rank(testresults))
> test.frame
   testresults rev.testresults. rank.testresults.
1           12              120                 1
2           14              118                 2
3           16              116                 3
4           18              114                 4
5           20              112                 5
6           22              110                 6
7           24              108                 7
8           26              106                 8
9           28              104                 9
10          30              102                10
11          32              100                11
12          34               98                12
13          36               96                13
14          38               94                14
15          40               92                15
16          42               90                16
17          44               88                17
18          46               86                18
19          48               84                19
20          50               82                20
21          52               80                21
22          54               78                22
23          56               76                23
24          58               74                24
25          60               72                25
26          62               70                26
27          64               68                27
28          66               66                28
29          68               64                29
30          70               62                30
31          72               60                31
32          74               58                32
33          76               56                33
34          78               54                34
35          80               52                35
36          82               50                36
37          84               48                37
38          86               46                38
39          88               44                39
40          90               42                40
41          92               40                41
42          94               38                42
43          96               36                43
44          98               34                44
45         100               32                45
46         102               30                46
47         104               28                47
48         106               26                48
49         108               24                49
50         110               22                50
51         112               20                51
52         114               18                52
53         116               16                53
54         118               14                54
55         120               12                55
```

I am sure I have overlooked a simple solution to this problem, thank you in advance to anyone who can help or point me in the right direction.

Best,
Maria

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subtract your values from the maximum value and then add the minimum value.  For example:

```
x <- seq(1, 5, by = .4)
x
[1] 1.0 1.4 1.8 2.2 2.6 3.0 3.4 3.8 4.2 4.6 5.0

(max(x) - x) + min(x)

[1] 5.0 4.6 4.2 3.8 3.4 3.0 2.6 2.2 1.8 1.4 1.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I have been trying to figure it out with some sort of fancy function for days X-)